# Event loop inside an event loop? - module should not be dependend on an outside event loop to exist

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm currently developing a discord bot using the discord.py API wrapper.
I am also working on an API wrapper for https://api.vrmasterleague.com (VRML) which is based on individual requests and not a continuous session as I understand the discord API works.
For now I only want to use the VRML API from inside the Discord bot, but I want to code it as a separate module to be able to reuse it later

I would like my VRML wrapper to utilize asynchronous functionality to which I am very new. My first idea was to take advantage of the event loop started by Discord.py and just expect `await` calls. However, this is not very useful if I want to use it outside of an event loop later on.

- Can I just start a second event loop inside my VRML API without disturbing or blocking the discord.py event loop?
- Are there conventions for something like this in place?
- How would you advise me to go about this?

Edit: Some background:
I have only just started coding the VRML API wrapper, so not much to show there. Basically how I think I want this to work is the following. This is probably a bit pseudo-code but it should give you an idea.

Discord bot:

```py
import discord
import VRML

client = discord.Client()

@client.event()
async def on_message(msg):
    message = msg.strip
    if message.content.startswith("!team"):
        # message should look like this: '!team <team_id>'
        response = message.channel.send('One moment please...')
        team_id = message.content.strip().split()[1]
        team = await VRML.get_team(team_id)
        response.edit(content = f"name: {team.name}, rank: {team.rank}")

client.run(token)
```

VRML:

```py
import .http as http

class Team:
    def __init__(self, id, name, rank):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank

async def get_team(team_id: str):
    data = await http.get_team_data(team_id)
    # data looks like this: {'id': 12345, 'name': 'Team Gravity', 'rank': 1}
    return Team(**data)
```

VRML.http:

```py
import aiohttp
import json

async def request(method, url):
    await with aiohttp.Session() as session:
        await with session.request(method, url) as r:
            data = json.loads(r.text(encoding='utf-8')

            # request success, return data
            if r.status == 200:
                return data

async def get_team_data(team_id):
    method = "GET"
    url = f"https://api.vrmasterleague.com/Teams/{team_id}"
    data = await request(method, url)
    return data
```

The problem arising is, that for the async-await-calls in the VRML module to work expects an existing asyncio event loop, here opened by discord.py. But if I want to use the VRML module somewhere else, where there is no event loop, I can't do that right now.
Therefore, can I create an event loop in the VRML module so it's independent without disrupting/blocking any event loops outside? The discord bot should still be able to react to messages while it waits for the API to response.

Comment: You can improve your question *tremendously* by posting the code you currently have.

Comment: You can provide an async API and a non-async one on top of it. The async one would be used in all async contexts, and the non-async one would be a simple convenience layer that creates an event loop and drives the async calls with `loop.run_until_complete()` or equivalent.